# navigation does not work with ng-if condtion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

hi i need help from you guys, when i add in ul  with ng-if condition navigation does not work, how to solve this please help

```
    <nav id="menu" class="nav-main" role="navigation">
            <ul class="nav nav-main" ng-if=" $ctrl.getCurrentUser().user_type == 'Customer'">
                <li class="">
                    <a href="/dashboard">
                        <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <span>Dashboard</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-parent">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-table" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <span>Jobs</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-children">
                        <li><a href="/addjob">Add New Job</a></li>
              </ul>
                </li>

<ul class="nav nav-main" ng-if=" $ctrl.getCurrentUser().user_type == 'Customer'">
```

Comment: use ng-show instead of ng-if.

Comment: where......in which tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem, below solution worked for me.

Define in your controller

> $scope.user = $this->getCurrentUser();

And use ng-show instant of ng-if

`<ul class="nav nav-main" ng-show=" user.user_type == 'Customer'">`

Please try this if it works for you.

Comment: Please mark it correct if it works for you :) @AdeelKhan and close this question.